# How to let the System.Threading.Timer wait until the process inside is done?

Tags: java, multithreading, timer

how can I make my timer wait until the process inside is done? This is my code

```
System.Threading.Timer mTimer = new System.Threading.Timer((o) =>
{
    //Do anything here

},null,0,5000);
```

And I want my timer to wait the process inside until it is finished. How can I do that?

Thank you!

Comment: what do you want to achieve?

Comment: My timer is started each 5 seconds. And in that time, my code inside the timer works. But if it takes more than 5 seconds, I want the timer doesn't start until that code finish.

Comment: Why is this tagged java? It's not Java. Please fix the tags.

Comment: Hmm, I used another timer. :|